# How to read excel filenames and extensions(xls,xlsx) under the folder?

Tags: c#, console-application

Is it possible to read all the excel filenames and ext(xls,xlsx) under the Folder?

[This is the folder name and I want to read all the excel filenames and ext(xls,xlsx)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFt6m.png)

The below code is what I tried but I want to read all the filenames with ext. Can any one give the best suggestion to get the solution.

```
    private static void ReadExcelFileSheetWithOleDb()
    {
        //Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0   --- Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
        //D:\\List_of_cid.xlsx

        string con = string.Empty;

        //string ext = Path.GetExtension("./Excel_Folder/List_of_cid.xlsx").ToLower();
        //string path = Path.GetFullPath("~/Excel_Folder/").ToString();

        //string[] fileArrayxls = Directory.GetFiles(@"~\Excel_Folder\", "*.xls");
        //string[] fileArrayxlsx = Directory.GetFiles(@"~\Excel_Folder\", "*.xlsx");
        

        string ext = Path.GetExtension("D:\\List_of_cid.xlsx").ToLower();
        

       
        if (ext.Trim() == ".xls")
        {
            // con = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + "; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;'";

            con = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\\List_of_cid.xlsx; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;'";
        }
        else if (ext.Trim() == ".xlsx")
        {
            con = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\\List_of_cid.xlsx; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;'";
        }

        using (OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(con))
        {
            // OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            try
            {

                oledbConn.Open();

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", oledbConn);

                OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();

                oleda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                oleda.Fill(ds, "List_of_cid");

                foreach (var m in ds.Tables[0].DefaultView)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(((DataRowView)m).Row.ItemArray[0] + " " + ((DataRowView)m).Row.ItemArray[1]);

                }

                // oledbConn.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error :" + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm new to the coding.

Comment: What's wrong with the `Directory.GetFiles` in the code you commented out?

Comment: In this scenario "Directory.GetFiles" is not working properly that's why I commented .

string[] fileArrayxls = Directory.GetFiles(@"~\Excel_Folder\", "*.xls");

when I write this line it is not executing properly..

Comment: You're specifying a relative path to the `Excel_Folder` folder, so the current location will be used as the root. That location might be (say) a `...bin\Debug` folder depending on your project's build settings, so unless you're copying `Excel_Folder` as part of the build it won't be found. I suggest you start by supplying an absolute path (say, `D:\...\Excel_Folder`) to `Directory.GetFiles()` to see whether that works.